# Configure jQuery datetimepicker with attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have lots of forms in my MVC3 application that require the user to input dates.

The requirement of the date given could be one of many cases, i.e a Date with a time, just a date, a date in the past, a date and time in the past, a date in the future, a date and time in the future etc...

So, at the moment I give the  a different class depending in what is required.  For example....

```
$("input.input-date-past").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: 1, showButtonPanel: true, maxDate: -0 });
```

...configures a date picker that restricts the users choice to date in the past only.

All this is working OK, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

I'm thinking that I could give the view model properties an attribute that would define what type of input was required. i.e

```
[Required]
[PastDate]
public DateTime SomeDateFromThePast { get; set; }

[Required]
[FutureDate]
public DateTime SomeDateFromTheFuture { get; set; }

[Required]
[FutureDateTime] // Requires a time to be given i.e "01/01/2012 09:00"
public DateTime SomeDateTimeFromTheFuture { get; set; }

etc..
```

Then in an Shared/EditorTemplate with `@model System.DateTime`, which will interrogate the attributes given to the property and set the class of the  as required.

Does that sound OK?  Or does it stink?

If OK, how do you interrogate the attributes given to the property?

If it stinks, any other suggestions?

Many thanks,

ETFairfax.

Comment: Francesco's awesome [MVC Controls Toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20Annotations) can do this via DateRangeAttribute. I email Francesco so he will probably chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own hooks into ASP.NET MVC's unobtrusive validation to write to `data-` attributes.

This tutorial should get you started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a custom DateTime validation method (there are a number of tutorials if you search Google)? That way, you can have it look only at items DateTime.Now() depending on whether you want to look into the past or the future.

As to your question of whether this is a good idea or not, well, I think it is good in one sense that you should check your input on the server-side. However, I don't think, from a usability standpoint, that it is a good idea to not have the client-side validation. If you don't want users selecting dates in the future, then I think it is good that you're limiting their ability to select dates in the future.